# File not found exception while running DockerFile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Here my DockerFile :-

```
FROM openjdk:10
ENV AQUILA_HOME /data/config
#USER root
#VOLUME /tmp
ADD a2i-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
#RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

My jar is spring boot application which refers configuration file from some directory [/data/config/config.properties]
I am building DockerFile successfully by command

```
sudo docker build -t dockImgName/a2i-web:v1 .
```

But while running it by command

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -t dockImgName/a2i-web:v1
```

giving exception as :

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/config/config.properties (No such file or directory)
```

I am running this dcoker command from directory containing DockerFile and my jar
Do I need to set any configuration to get config file directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. When the container tries to run it is not able to find properties file.

You need to add config.properties file to your docker image.

```
ADD path_to_config_file/config.properties /data/config/config.properties
```

***NOTE: `path_to_config_file` refers to the file path in your local where you are building the dockerfile***

Comment: what is path_to_config_file?

Comment: While building, it giving error as "ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder317118205/config.properties: no such file or directory"

Comment: Putting config.properties file in same directory as DockerFile is solved this problem..It helped

Comment: How to bind folder ? I have may files to be used under folder

Comment: I think dir can be similarly added like file, 
`ADD path_to_config_dir/ /data/config/`